# glBufferData very slow with big textures (sprites sheets) in Cocos2d-x 3.3

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-x

I'm working with Cocos2d-x to port my PC game to Android. 
For the sprites part, I wanted to optimize the rendering process so I decided to dynamically create sprites sheets that contain the frames for all the sprites.

Unfortunately, this makes the rendering process about 10-15 times slower than using small textures containing only the frames for the current sprite (on mobile device, on Windows everything runs smoothly).

I initially thought it could be related to the switching between the sheets (big textures like 4096*4096) when the rendering process would display one sprite from one sheet, then another from another sheet and so on... making a lot of switches between huge textures.
So I sorted the sprites before "putting" their frames in the sprites sheets, and I can confirm that the switches are now non-existent.

After a long investigation, profiling, tests etc... I finally found that one Open GL function takes all the time:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(_quadVerts[0]) * _numberQuads * 4, _quadVerts, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

Calling this function takes a long time (profiler says more than 20 ms per call) if I use the big texture, quite fast if I use small ones (about 2 ms).

I don't really know Open GL, I'm using it because Cocos2d-x uses it, and I'm not at ease to try to debug/optimize the engine because I really think they are far better than me for that :)

I might be misunderstanding something and I'm stuck on this since several days and I have no idea of what I can do now.

Any clues ?

Note: I'm talking about glBufferData but I have the same issue with glBindFramebuffer, very slow with big textures. I assume this is all the same topic.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is normally a costly call to do as glBufferData involves CPU to GPU transfer.
But the logic behind Renderer::drawBatchedQuads is to flush the quads that have been buffered in a temporary array. The more quads you have to render, the more data have to be transferred.
Since the quads properties (positions, texture, colors) are likely to change each frame, a CPU to GPU transfer is required every frame as hinted by the flag GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW.

According to specs:

GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW: The data store contents will be modified repeatedly and used many times as the source for GL drawing command.

There are possible alternatives to glBufferData such as glMapBuffer or glBufferSubData that could be used for comparison.